# JPanel button is not at the correct place

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager

i made a custom JFrame for the desktop application and i added a JPanel on the very top of the app to serve as a subtitute of the title box. the problem is when i added a button it located right in the middle of the JPanel instead of the usual left top. AND it would not move even if i set it at a different location.
here is the code:

```
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Hello");
        f.setResizable(true);
        JPanel pa = new JPanel();
        JButton btn = new JButton("Exit");

        btn.setBackground(Color.white);
        btn.setText("Button");
        btn.setSize(300, 80);
        btn.setLocation(50, 0);

        pa.setBackground(Color.red);
        pa.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width,60));
        pa.add(btn);

        f.setBackground(Color.white);
        f.setUndecorated(true);
        f.getContentPane().add(pa, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        f.setSize(new Dimension(width,height));
        f.setLocation(200, 200);
        f.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: [How to Use Panels-Setting the Layout Manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html#layout) -> [Using Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html)

Comment: By "the usual left top" do you mean "usual" as in "where you'd expect it to go" or as in "where you've seen Swing place this previously"? If the former, read the Swing docs as Axel suggests (and the [menu](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) docs, if that's what you're trying to create). If the latter, an example of a component that is working as you intend would be helpful to compare against.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a `BorderLayout` in the frame. You can do the same thing in the panel.

```
pa.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
pa.add(btn, BorderLayout.WEST);
```

In general, `setLocation` tends to fight against the layout manager, so you usually don't want to use it unless you're going to position *everything* by hand.

Comment: that is one way to do it, but BorderLayout way is not very good way because i also want to add another button next to it.

Answer (score 1):

> that is one way to do it, but `BorderLayout` way is not very good way because i also want to add another button next to it.

Then what this might need is a `FlowLayout` using `FlowLayout.LEADING` as the alignment.

But as general tips:

1. Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI (showing **all** components) at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used.
2. For better help sooner, post a  
   [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/) of your attempt.